# Copying folders from a source folder to a destination folder using xcopy batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that is copying data from a source folder to a destination folder. A text file called list.txt decides which folders from the source folder will be copied to the dest folder.
The contents of the text file, list.txt, are:

```
F:\200208
F:\200210
F:\200214
```

The batch file is:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (list.txt) do (
        xcopy /s /i "%%i" "D:\username\Videos\%%i"
    )
pause
```

However, when I run the batch file, I get the following error messages:

```
Invalid path
0 File(s) copied
Invalid path
0 File(s) copied
Invalid path
0 File(s) copied
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The name of the drive in which this batch file is residing is F
and folders with name 200208, 200210 & 200214 do exist in that same drive F. Also, the dest folder exists.

Can someone point out where the issue is?

Comment: Put an `ECHO` at the beginning of the line inside your loop so you can can see the problem. It would look like `ECHO xcopy /s /i "%%i" "D:\username\Videos\%%i"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination path in your code is resolving to `"D:\username\Videos\F:\200208"`.  That is why you are getting an invalid path.

You just want the folder name so change `%%i` to `%%~nxi` in the destination path.